# Making sqlalchemy not drop (or truncate) temporary tables on commit

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create and then use a temporary table in postgres with sqlalchemy. I Want to create the table my_table with the 'Temporary' prefix, then commit it to the database, so I can use it again within the same session.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Table

my_table = Table('my_temp_table', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY'])

my_table.create(session.bind)
session.commit() # required to access the table
```

But when I go to query that table in the same session

```
session.query(my_table).filter(my_table.id == 2).all()
```

The table no longer exists.

I know there's the 'ON COMMIT' option which can be set when creating a temporary table, which when set to 'PRESERVE ROWS' should not drop (or truncate) the table.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html

By default ON COMMIT should be set to PRESERVER ROWS in postgres, but the table is still dropped.

Is there a way in sqlalchemy to create a temporary table with ON COMMIT set to PRESERVE ROWS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`postgresql_on_commit`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-table-options) parameter which is a Postgresql dialect-specific construction for creating tables. i.e.:

```
my_table = Table('my_temp_table', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY'],
    postgresql_on_commit='PRESERVE ROWS')
```

However, taking a closer look to the `my_table.create()` call I think you are trying to pass `session.get_bind()` instead of `session.bind`

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks! If only we were using 1.0! Any way to do this still using 0.9.9?